# Lizmap - QGIS server - PostgreSQL error layer not valid

Tags: postgresql, qgis-3, lizmap

I've installed Lizmap in Windows 10 but a problem is that I haven't the edition button and can't display layers from PostgreSQL. I have a "service non disponible" with "layer not valide" error in QGIS Server log when layer is added into QGIS project from PostgreSQL. Connection with PostgreSQL is working and I have authz, count... tables created in PostgreSQL after installation, but always error persist. What is the key? I installed Apache 2.41+ fcgi module, qgis-ltr 3.4 and qgis-ltr server 3.4, PostgreSQL 11 with PostGIS. Also with QGIS Server getmap url to QGIS project I have a same error "layer not valid" in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

probably You managed it already to get it work. I had a similar behavoir and my problem was, that in my QGIS-project file the athentification to the PostgreSQL-layers wasn't done in the basic way. Lizmap needs QGIS-project files where the user and passwort are stored as plain text in order to connect to the PostgreSQL database.

Comment: I would rephrase a bit. QGIS Server needs to access to the layer stored in PostgreSQL. So either the credentials are in indeed stored in the QGS project, OR you can use the PostgreSQL service file (recommended way to not share the user&password in the QGS file). Using the master password, you need to set it also on QGIS Server with ENV variable, but Lizmap won't be able to edit data (because only QGIS Server will be able to access the data)